# How to concatenate variable string data to a row in a dataframe based on numeric value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlwings

I have a pandas dataframe `result`, looks like this:

```
    Weekday Day Store1  Store2  Store3  Store4  Store5
0   Mon     6   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
1   Tue     7   42.0    33.0    23.0    42.0    21.0
2   Wed     8   43.0    29.0    13.0    33.0    22.0
3   Thu     9   45.0    24.0    20.0    29.0    18.0
4   Fri     10  48.0    21.0    22.0    37.0    22.0
5   Sat     11  34.0    22.0    23.0    34.0    18.0
0   Mon     13  39.0    21.0    21.0    25.0    21.0
1   Tue     14  39.0    20.0    18.0    0.0     19.0
2   Wed     15  46.0    26.0    18.0    31.0    24.0
3   Thu     16  38.0    21.0    15.0    45.0    29.0
4   Fri     17  42.0    21.0    21.0    41.0    20.0
5   Sat     18  40.0    25.0    15.0    36.0    19.0
0   Mon     20  39.0    22.0    23.0    36.0    19.0
1   Tue     21  31.0    18.0    16.0    35.0    23.0
2   Wed     22  33.0    25.0    17.0    39.0    22.0
3   Thu     23  34.0    24.0    19.0    18.0    27.0
4   Fri     24  33.0    18.0    24.0    43.0    24.0
5   Sat     25  38.0    22.0    20.0    40.0    12.0
0   Mon     27  41.0    21.0    18.0    31.0    23.0
1   Tue     28  32.0    21.0    14.0    23.0    14.0
2   Wed     29  33.0    18.0    15.0    19.0    23.0
3   Thu     30  36.0    21.0    21.0    23.0    18.0
4   Fri     1   40.0    30.0    24.0    38.0    23.0
5   Sat     2   40.0    19.0    22.0    38.0    21.0
```

Notice how `Day` goes from 6 to 30, then back to 1, and 2. In this example, it's referring to
September 6, 2021 - October 2nd, 2021.

I currently have a variable `PrimaryMonth = September` and `SecondaryMonth = October`

I know that I can do `result['Month'] = 'September'` but it will list all the `Month` values as September, I'd like to find a way, if possible, to iterate through the rows so that when it reaches the bottom `1` and `2` it will show October in the new `Month` column.

Is it possible to do a For loop or some other iteration to accomplish this? I was initially brainstorming some pseudocode

```
#for row in result:
    # while Day <= 31 
        #concat PrimaryMonth
        #else concat SecondaryMonth
```

You can kind of get an idea of where I want to go with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many things are easier if you use proper date formats...

```
date_str = 'Monday, September 6, 2021 - Saturday, October 2, 2021'
new_index = pd.date_range(*map(pd.to_datetime, date_str.split(' - ')))
dates = pd.DataFrame(index=new_index)
dates['day'] = dates.index.day
dates.columns = ['Day']

df = pd.merge(dates, df, 'outer')
df.index = dates.index

df['month'] = df.index.month_name()
print(df.dropna())
```

Output:

```
            Day Weekday  Store1  Store2  Store3  Store4  Store5      month
2021-09-06    6     Mon     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0  September
2021-09-07    7     Tue    42.0    33.0    23.0    42.0    21.0  September
2021-09-08    8     Wed    43.0    29.0    13.0    33.0    22.0  September
2021-09-09    9     Thu    45.0    24.0    20.0    29.0    18.0  September
2021-09-10   10     Fri    48.0    21.0    22.0    37.0    22.0  September
2021-09-11   11     Sat    34.0    22.0    23.0    34.0    18.0  September
2021-09-13   13     Mon    39.0    21.0    21.0    25.0    21.0  September
2021-09-14   14     Tue    39.0    20.0    18.0     0.0    19.0  September
2021-09-15   15     Wed    46.0    26.0    18.0    31.0    24.0  September
2021-09-16   16     Thu    38.0    21.0    15.0    45.0    29.0  September
2021-09-17   17     Fri    42.0    21.0    21.0    41.0    20.0  September
2021-09-18   18     Sat    40.0    25.0    15.0    36.0    19.0  September
2021-09-20   20     Mon    39.0    22.0    23.0    36.0    19.0  September
2021-09-21   21     Tue    31.0    18.0    16.0    35.0    23.0  September
2021-09-22   22     Wed    33.0    25.0    17.0    39.0    22.0  September
2021-09-23   23     Thu    34.0    24.0    19.0    18.0    27.0  September
2021-09-24   24     Fri    33.0    18.0    24.0    43.0    24.0  September
2021-09-25   25     Sat    38.0    22.0    20.0    40.0    12.0  September
2021-09-27   27     Mon    41.0    21.0    18.0    31.0    23.0  September
2021-09-28   28     Tue    32.0    21.0    14.0    23.0    14.0  September
2021-09-29   29     Wed    33.0    18.0    15.0    19.0    23.0  September
2021-09-30   30     Thu    36.0    21.0    21.0    23.0    18.0  September
2021-10-01    1     Fri    40.0    30.0    24.0    38.0    23.0    October
2021-10-02    2     Sat    40.0    19.0    22.0    38.0    21.0    October
```

And no, no matter what you do, a for-loop is probably the wrong answer when it comes to pandas.

Comment: You added the dates manually with the line
`dates = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2021-09-06', '2021-10-02'))`

I am trying to automate the process. To be specific, the file I am extracting data from is an Excel file. One of the cells is a reference to the date but comes in a clumsy format. I parsed the date information out into the variables I mentioned above. I'm trying to use that information to assign date information to the existing dataframe, avoiding, if possible, manually assigning the date.

Comment: That date cell looks something like this: "'Monday, September 6, 2021 - Saturday, October 2, 2021'" Maybe I could use that to create the date format `2021-09-06` and `2021-10-02` respectively and assign those to a variable, and use that in the date format as you showed in your line above

Comment: I modified it to use your example string~